# How to change the hover colour on Office Fabric UI Nav component

Tags: reactjs

I have a Nav component in my react app, and I am trying to change the background colour of each item on hover. So far I have-

```
styles={{
  link: [
    {
      backgroundColor: "#232b2b",
      selectors: {
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  linkText: {
    color: "white"
  }
}}
```

but it is not changing the colour...does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I think it depends on what of kind of nav you use.... material-ui?, bootstrap?

Comment: @MatteoAngelotti I import it from the fabric site like this-import { Nav } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Nav';

Comment: I don't know you can try to overwrite the className with a new css

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

```js
styles={{
          link: {
            backgroundColor: '#232b2b',
            selectors: {
              '.ms-Nav-compositeLink:hover &': {
                color: 'red',
                backgroundColor: 'green',
              },
            },
          },
```